# Почему Photoshop показывает не верные размеры шрифта и название самого шрифта?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, photoshop

подскажите пожалуйста, почему фотошоп показывает не верные значения шрифта и его названия, и как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Вам при открытии `template.psd` - скорее всего будет выскакивать сообщение о том, что нужно заменить шрифты.

Это связано с тем, что у вас на pc/notebook не установлены указанные в этой таблице замены, шрифты.

Вам необходимо скачать и установить шрифты, указанные в этой табличке, после этого перезапустить `photoshop` - Только не в коем случае не нужно после замены при выходе сохранять изменения!